# Twitter api - foreach error

Tags: php, twitter

```html
$tweets = $twitter->get('followers/list', [
    'screen_name' => "zaraakai"
]);
foreach ($tweets as $tweetss) {
 var_dump($tweetss['users']['0']['1']['followers_count']);
}
```

This is the json returned after the call : https://pastebin.com/1NKagKZQ

I would like to get the  but i have this error: Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\INDEX.PHP on line 12
string(0) ""

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tweets->followers_count
```

```html
 $tweets = $twitter->get('users/show', [
     'screen_name' => $pseudo
 ]);
  
  This return json objetct so just $tweets->followers_count
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean?

```
$tweets = $twitter->get('followers/list', [
    'screen_name' => "zaraakai"
]);
foreach ($tweets as $tweetss) {
    var_dump($tweets['users']['0']['1']['followers_count']);
}
```

If so I would distinguish your interable variable name as it's very confusing what you have going on.

Comment: still error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the followers count for every user (I guess this based on your original code), you could try this:

```
$tweets = $twitter->get('followers/list', [
    'screen_name' => "zaraakai"
]);
foreach ($tweets->users as $usr) {
    var_dump($usr['followers_count']);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\CC\INDEX.PHP:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} throw

Comment: @ZaraaKai I updated my answer after taking another look at the JSON.